# Swift: Get the TruthDepth camera parameters for face tracking in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, camera-calibration

**My goal:**

I am trying to get the TruthDepth camera parameters (such as the intrinsic, extrinsic, lens distortion etc) for the TruthDepth camera while I am doing the face tracking. I read that there is examples and possible to that with [OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/camera-calibration-using-opencv/). I am just wondering should one achieve similar goals in Swift.

**What I have read and tried:**

I read that the apple documentation about ARCamera: [intrinsics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2875730-intrinsics) and AVCameraCalibrationData:
[extrinsicMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcameracalibrationdata/2881130-extrinsicmatrix) and [intrinsicMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcameracalibrationdata/2881135-intrinsicmatrix).

However, all I found was just the declarations for both `AVCameraCalibrationData` and `ARCamera`:

---

For `AVCameraCalibrationData`

---

For intrinsicMatrix

```
var intrinsicMatrix: matrix_float3x3 { get }
```

For extrinsicMatrix

```
var extrinsicMatrix: matrix_float4x3 { get }
```

I also read this post: [get Camera Calibration Data on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093509/how-can-i-get-camera-calibration-data-on-ios-aka-avcameracalibrationdata) and tried Bourne's suggestion:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        let ex = photo.depthData?.cameraCalibrationData?.extrinsicMatrix
        //let ex = photo.cameraCalibrationData?.extrinsicMatrix
        let int = photo.cameraCalibrationData?.intrinsicMatrix
        photo.depthData?.cameraCalibrationData?.lensDistortionCenter
        print ("ExtrinsicM: \(String(describing: ex))")
        print("isCameraCalibrationDataDeliverySupported: \(output.isCameraCalibrationDataDeliverySupported)")
    }
```

But it does not printing the matrix at all.

---

For `ARCamera` I have read from Andy Fedoroff's  [Focal Length of the camera used in RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623726/what-is-the-real-focal-length-of-the-camera-used-in-realitykit/62627471#62627471):

```
var intrinsics: simd_float3x3 { get }
func inst (){
    sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.focalLength
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        print(" Focal Length: \(String(describing: self.sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.focalLength))")
        print("Sensor Height: \(String(describing: self.sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.sensorHeight))")
        // SENSOR HEIGHT IN mm
        let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame
        // INTRINSICS MATRIX
        print("Intrinsics fx: \(String(describing: frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.0.x))")
        print("Intrinsics fy: \(String(describing: frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.1.y))")
        print("Intrinsics ox: \(String(describing: frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.2.x))")
        print("Intrinsics oy: \(String(describing: frame?.camera.intrinsics.columns.2.y))")
    }
}
```

It shows the render camera parameters:

```
Focal Length: Optional(20.784610748291016)
Sensor Height: Optional(24.0)
Intrinsics fx: Optional(1277.3052)
Intrinsics fy: Optional(1277.3052)
Intrinsics ox: Optional(720.29443)
Intrinsics oy: Optional(539.8974)
```

However, this only shows the render camera instead of the TruthDepth camera that I am using for face tracking.

---

So can anyone help me get started with getting the TruthDepth camera parameters as the documentation did not really show any example other than the declarations?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I am having a similar problem. Did you manage to get it using the accepted answer? If so, did you find the intrinsic parameters accurate for your application, and do they change over time? That would really help me for my 3D pose estimation project with front camera, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you cannot print the intrinsics is probably because you got `nil` in the optional chaining. You should have a look at Apple's remark [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2890249-cameracalibrationdata) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873909-depthdata).

> Camera calibration data is present only if you specified the `isCameraCalibrationDataDeliveryEnabled` and `isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled` settings when requesting capture. For camera calibration data in a capture that includes depth data, see the `AVDepthData` `cameraCalibrationData` property.

> To request capture of depth data alongside a photo (on supported devices), set the `isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled` property of your photo settings object to true when requesting photo capture. If you did not request depth data delivery, this property's value is `nil`.

So if you want to get the `intrinsicMatrix` and `extrinsicMatrix` of the TrueDepth camera, you should use `builtInTrueDepthCamera` as the input device, set the `isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled` of the pipeline's photo output to `true`, and set `isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled` to `true` when you capture the photo. Then you can access the intrinsic matrices in `photoOutput(_: didFinishProcessingPhoto: error:)` call back by accessing the `depthData.cameraCalibrationData` attribute of `photo` argument.

Here's a [code sample for setting up such a pipeline](https://github.com/Frost-Lee/insulin_calculator/blob/master/insulin_calculator/insulin_calculator/Model/EstimateImageCaptureManager.swift).